# java date format problems

Tags: java, date

I have a method that is taking a date and converting it to a long integer.

```
        Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < columns.size(); i++) {

        String colName = columns.get(i);

        if ("productionDate".equals( colName )) {
            row.put(colName, ((Date) obj[i]).getTime());
        } else {
            row.put(columns.get(i), obj[i]);
        }
```

I know this line is where it is changing the format, I'm looking for a way to convert it to MM-DD-YYYY

```
row.put(colName, ((Date) obj[i]).getTime());
```

Comment: A format is something you get when you convert it to a string.  A date is just a date, it doesn't have a format as such.

Comment: Sorry, i meant the way the date is displaying now is like: 1437973200000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, now that you've converted your `Date` to a `long`, if you want to display it as a date again in the format you specified you will need to:

1) Get it back to a `Date` object, i.e.

```
Date myDate = new Date(mylongvalue);
```

2) Use `SimpleDateFormat` to get a `String` in the format you want from the `Date`, i.e.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(myDate);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

The [answer by GriffeyDog](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35349733/642706) and other answers are correct in showing you how to generate a String from a java.util.Date or java.sql.Date object. But…

- The other Answers are using old outmoded classes.
- The other Answers fail to address the critical issue of time zone.
- You may find a better approach in retaining date-time objects rather than storing strings.

## java.time

Java 8 and later comes with the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework. These new classes supplant the old java.util.Date/.Calendar and java.text.SimpleTextFormat classes. Those old classes have proven to be confusing, troublesome, and flawed.

### From `java.sql.Date`

If getting a [`java.sql.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) object from a database (your question is not clear about this), you have date-only value without time-of-day nor time zone. So convert to the [java.time.LocalDate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class.

```
LocalDate localDate = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

### From `java.util.Date`

If getting a [`java.util.Date`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) object, be aware that is both a date and a time-of-day combined despite the name of the class. Convert to an `Instant`, a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time).

```
Instant instant = myJavaUtilDate.toInstant();
```

### Time Zone

From there adjust to a time zone in which you want your date to have a meaning. The date is not the same around the world for any given moment. A new day dawns earlier in the east. So just after midnight in Paris is still ‘yesterday’ in Montréal.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

Now use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to generate a String representation of the date value. The pattern codes are slightly different than those of the old java.text.SimpleDateFormat, so read the [class doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) carefully.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM-dd-uuuu" ); 
String output = zdt.format( formatter );
```

### ISO 8601

If you insist on storing Strings, I suggest changing your format to the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format `YYYY-MM-DD`. Such string values when sorted alphabetically also happen to be chronological. The java.time classes use ISO 8601 formats by default. So no need to specify a coded pattern. Just convert to a LocalDate, then call `toString`.

```
String output = zdt.toLocalDate().toString();
```

### Store Date-Time Objects

Better yet, store `LocalDate` objects as the value in your Map rather than `String`. Only generate a particular String representation in a particular format when necessary, such as for presentation to a user. Given that `LocalDate` is now built into Java, you can confidently use it throughout your code knowing it is always available.

Comment: Certainly using the `java.time` package is preferred (if the OP can use Java 8). I was just answering the OP's question as posed.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like:

Date likedDate = new Date(); //Is a made up date
row.put (colName.DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(likedDated));

SHORT is indicating the format you desire.